# Using reflection in Powershell with different .NET framework versions

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

I am trying to reflect some assembly attributes from a .NET assembly. I am using Powershell 2.0, but the assembly was written using .NET Framework 4.5.1, so when I try the following command:

```
$assembly = [Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("C:\Path\To\My\Assembly.dll")
```

I get the following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Path\To\My\Assembly.dll'
>   or one of  its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer
>   than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

I've tried several variations on that theme (e.g. Assembly.Load, Assembly.LoadFrom) but with no improvement. Any ideas? I can get basic information using Get-Command, but that does not return all assembly attributes that I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

Install a newer version of PowerShell (version 3.0 and 4.0 is supported on Windows Server 2008 R2)

Force PowerShell.exe to use .NET v4 instead of .NET 2.0 (as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5069146/712649)), by providing a config file with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration> 
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/> 
    </startup> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: We installed Powershell 3 in the end.